# WordPress uploads do not show up and I see the white screen of death in some cases

Tags: theme-development, themes, wp-admin, uploads, media-library

Recently I have installed my own-made theme on my WordPress and after that a few problems have occurred.

> Firstly when I upload a photo or file from my site's admin panel it
>   does not show up under Media tab. and when I try to define a thumbnail
>   for a post I cannot see the photos. Therefore I deactivated my
>   own-made theme and changed it to 2017 WordPress theme. after that when
>   I uploaded images they showed up in my Media tab but again when using
>   one of them as a post thumbnail (after reactivating my theme) they
>   showed up like below:

[image]

I've tried several ways to fix this issue such as:

**1) Deactivating my whole plugins.**

**2) Increase PHP Memory Limit by editing the wp-config.php file:**

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

**3) Changing file permissions of my site's uploads folder and etc.**

> Secondly when I activate my own-made theme some times I see the
>   popular white screen of death.(For example when I define a new
>   category and press the publish key I get redirected to a white empty
>   page) And I don't know what problem my theme has that makes this
>   happen.

What changes must be done to my own-made theme in order to fix the white screen of death and uploads issues?

Comment: After you redefined the memory limit in WordPress, did you run a `php-info.php` to make sure the memory had actually increased?

Comment: @KennethOdle No I didn't. How should I do it?

Comment: Create a file name `php-info.php`. Edit to contain a single line: `<?php phpinfo(); ?> ` Upload it to your website and view it in a web browser. It will tell you what actual memory allowance is. Because of the way some servers are set up, changing the value in `wp-config.php` sometimes doesn't actually change the memory value, so it's a good idea to check.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot I turned **debugging mode** on I found that my functions.php file has a problem as soon as I fixed it both ***uploads problem*** and ***white screen*** of death issue were disappeared. Thanks a million.